# How to create a class that inherits from an entity object??? (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework

I have a Silverlight Bussiness Application, I'm using Entity Framework Data model, and I have an entity class called Clients, with some properties: Name, LastName, Address, etc. I need to create a class that inherits from Clients class, I need something like this...

```
public class ClientWithSubClients : Clients
{
    public bool HasSubClients { get; set; }
    public List<Clients> SubClients { get; set; }
}
```

I need it to have in the same class, the information of the Client, and the information of the SubClients... On server side works fine, but I need to use it on client side, and in the silverlight project I can't see the class definition... any idea...

Thanks... Miguel

Comment: a. By "Entity Framework Data model" do you mean "Entity Framework Database First"? b. How are you generating your entity classes? (Default generation, POCO T4s, Self Tracking T4s, ...) c. Do you need to be able to persist ClientWithSubClients to the database? d. How are you adding your classes to the silverlight project?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to see the entity framework types directly in Silverlight, because EF relies on the full .net framework, and is in your case a server-only technology.

To expose the EF types to a Silverlight client, you need some sort of server side service as a wrapper.  I've used WCF data services (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx) for this exact requirement and it works quite nicely.  WCF RIA services (http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/get-started-with-wcf-ria-services) is another alternative as well.

I think if you are only ever going have Silverlight clients consuming your data, WCF RIA services is the best choice.  If you want a more broadly accessible service, use WCF Data Services.

We use WCF data services, because we have silverlight apps, WPF apps, and even Excel spreadsheets consuming the services.